# PrimeNg Multiselect is failing unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, primeng

I am running unit test cases, for my component which contains many of primeng components, unit test cases are passing for most of the components except the multi select, It is giving the following error:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.documentClickListener()') in D:/mdp-internaltools-app/src/index.spec.ts (line 126499)
    ngOnDestroy@D:/mdp-internaltools-app/src/index.spec.ts:126499:35 <- webpack:///~/primeng/components/multiselect/multiselect.js:232:0
    ngOnDestroy
    destroyInternal
```

Did anyone also faced the issue with the multi select component of primeng?

Comment: I regulary do with any library, and it's usually because I didn't mock the component / service. Try mocking it and see if it works for you.

Comment: @trichetriche can you please provide the code, how to mock it

Comment: No I can't, because it depends on how you used it. Go to [this page](https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-with-a-dependency) to learn more about that

Comment: @trichetriche is there any way to override a lifecycle method of a third party component

Comment: Yes, by mocking it. I once had to mock 12 functions in order to make my test work.

Comment: @trichetriche could you please a small code example, so that I could go about it

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I found that you have to import the MultiSelectModule in your TestBed configuration. All primeng controls used in the component template must be imported in the imports section to prevent errors.